# SQL query tuning suggestion required

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a customer table in an Oracle database with 10 million rows as of today. Every day, one view is creating like customer_1001 on top of customer table and below is the sample view definition.

```
Create view customer_1001 
As
    Select <60 columns> 
    From customer a
    Where trunc(a.create_dt) = (select max(trunc(a.create_dt))  
                                from customer) ;
```

And `Customer` table has composite PK on `Cust_ID` and `create_dt` only and no any other options defined in DDL definition.

Could you please suggest how can I tune the `Customer` table DDL to get the query results quickly on top of view?

We are querying the view multiple times in our ETL process. Please help me.

Comment: I provided some initial guidance but we really need to see the queries in your ETL process that *use* the view in order to properly advise.

Answer (score 2):

First, if all you want is to get the latest load using the logic you've shared, you might want to try a windowing function:

```
    select *
      from (select /*+ parallel(8) */
                   c.*,
                   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(create_dt) DESC) seq
             from customer c)
     where seq = 1
```

However, that you are creating a view suggests you have other queries that intend to use the view. Those queries entirely change what your needs are, and so you'd have to share what they are in order to give more advice. If you are going to query for a particular customer ID, than you'd want to ensure that you've indexed the predicate column and that your windowing function is partitioned by that column:

```
    create index customer_1ix on customer(customer_id);

    create view myview as
    select *
      from (select c.*,
                   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY TRUNC(create_dt) DESC) seq
             from customer c)
     where seq = 1;

     select * from myview where customer_id = 1234;
```

If you intend to query by other filters, the logic you'd need in the view to make that perform well would need to be adjusted. Every top level query against a view makes an entirely new and different SQL when the two are considered together. There's no way to make a view always perform well regardless of how it is used.

Lastly, if you anticipate several different ways of querying that narrow down the results significantly you may be better off using a subquery after all. But you'll need to ensure you properly index things. Your existing query would need:

```
create index customer_1ix on customer(trunc(create_dt));

select *
  from customer
 where TRUNC(create_dt) = (SELECT MAX(c2.create_date) FROM customer c2)
```

If you correlated it so it looks for the latest create_dt for a specific customer, then you'd need:

```
create index customer_1ix on customer(customer_id,trunc(create_dt));

select *
  from customer c1
 where TRUNC(create_dt) = (SELECT MAX(c2.create_date) 
                             FROM customer c2 
                            WHERE c2.customer_id = c1.customer_id)
```

etc..

Which method is best depends entirely on how you plan to query the view. Also double-check your need for the `TRUNC`s..  unless those dates contain time portions that all differ from each other and your business logic requires you treat them all the same by day, you should avoid using `TRUNC` and simply compare dates to dates.